# getResources() from within an enumeration -- Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've just started with `Android Development`. Now, I want to make an `enumeration`. Each enum-object within that enumeration, I want to assign a name to. I want to get that name from my project resources (`res/values/strings.xml`).

But from within the enumeration type, I can't call `getResources().getString(R.string.string_name)`.

Is that because the enumeration doesn't extend an activity or something?

How can I fetch the strings from the resources anyway?

Thanks!

P.S. The enumeration is not nested within a class. If it is possible, I want to keep it as a seperate file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getResources().getString()` is simply a shorthand for `getActivity().getResources().getString()`.

So `getResources()` still rely on having a context (activity, fragment, context, etc).

To overcome this, i personally extended the Application class and made a public static Context available, so you can always access resources and such in your entire application, no matter if you're in an activity or a POJO.

Example:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    public static Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        context = getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

With this, you can always call:

```
MyApp.context.getResources().getString(xxxx);
```

Comment: "getResources().getString() is simply a shorthand for getActivity().getResources().getString()" **this is only true within a Fragment, which is not the case here**.

Answer (score 0):

Enumerators are implicitly static. As in when they are created, your activity and therefor its Context is nowhere to be found. If there's no Context, there are no Resources either.

Perhaps what you want to use is a static class with custom constructor instead of an enumerator. Example:

```
private static class MyConstants {
    private Resources mResources;
    public String constant1;
    public String constant2;
    public String constant3;
    public MyConstants(Context ctx) {
        mResources = ctx.getResources();
        constant1 = mResources.getString(R.id.string1);
        constant2 = mResources.getString(R.id.string2);
        constant3 = mResources.getString(R.id.string3);
    }
}

MyConstants mConstants;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_book);

    mConstants = new MyConstants(this);
    Log.e(TAG, mConstants.constant1);
    ...
 }
```

Comment: @ChrisStratton I think you misunderstood. `MyConstants` is an inner class inside a class that extends `Activity`.